# How do you use offsetof() on a struct?

Tags: c, struct, offset

I want the offsetof() the param line in `mystruct1`.  I've tried

```
offsetof(struct mystruct1, rec.structPtr1.u_line.line)
```

and also

```
offsetof(struct mystruct1, line)
```

but neither works.

```
union {
    struct mystruct1 structPtr1;
    struct mystruct2 structPtr2;
} rec;

typedef struct mystruct1 {
    union {
        struct {
            short len;
            char buf[2];
        } line;

        struct {
            short len;
        } logo;

    } u_line;
};
```

Comment: Can't you provide us with compilable code for the structure definitions?  Or omit the `struct mystruct2`...

Comment: what do you mean by "neither works"?

Comment: Note that the keyword `typedef` is not needed in this example. It is a vacuous use of it since there is no name given to become an alias for `struct mystruct1`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `offsetof()` macro takes two arguments.  The C99 standard says (in §7.17 `<stddef.h>`):

> ```
> offsetof(type, member-designator)
> ```
>
> which expands to an integer constant expression that has type `size_t`, the value of
>   which is the offset in bytes, to the structure member (designated by member-designator),
>   from the beginning of its structure (designated by type). The type and member designator
>   shall be such that given
>
> ```
> static type t;
> ```
>
> then the expression `&(t.member-designator)` evaluates to an address constant.

So, you need to write:

```
offsetof(struct mystruct1, u_line.line);
```

However, we can observe that the answer will be zero since `mystruct1` contains a `union` as the first member (and only), and the `line` part of it is one element of the union, so it will be at offset 0.

Comment: It would be great to show an example however short it may be of it being used (declare the struct and use `offsetof`)

Comment: There are a number of questions where I do show examples, including [Finding offset of a structure element in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18749784/15168).

Answer (score 2):

Your `struct mystruct1` has 1 member named `u_line`. You can see the offset of that member

```
offsetof(struct mystruct1, u_line); // should be 0
```

or of members down the line if you specify each "level of parenthood"

```
offsetof(struct mystruct1, u_line.line);
offsetof(struct mystruct1, u_line.line.buf);
offsetof(struct mystruct1, u_line.logo);
```

Answer (score 2):

A great article to read on this is:

[Learn a new trick with the offsetof() macro](http://www.embedded.com/design/prototyping-and-development/4024941/Learn-a-new-trick-with-the-offsetof--macro)

I use the offsetof macro frequently in my embedded code, together with the modified SIZEOF macro as discussed in the article.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, AFAIK, `offsetof` is intended to be used with immediate members of the struct only (am I right on this?).

Secondly, knowing the internal details of popular `offsetof` implementations I can suggest trying

```
offsetof(struct mystruct1, u_line.line)
```

This should work. Whether it is standard-compliant is an open question for me.

P.S. Judging by @Jonathan Leffler's answer, this should actually work.

Comment: "am I right on this?" I don't think so (after testing gcc). gcc accepts "deep" members on `offsetof` expressions.

Comment: @pmg: Well, questions like this can't really be answered by "testing".

Comment: Right @Andrey. The quote from the Standard posted in Jonathan's answer allows for using `offsetof` with "deep" members.