# How does the C offsetof macro work?

Tags: c, macros, offset

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [Why does this C code work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713963/why-does-this-c-code-work) 
>   [How do you use offsetof() on a struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180290/how-do-you-use-offsetof-on-a-struct)

I read about this offsetof macro on the Internet, but it doesn't explain what it is used for.

```
#define offsetof(a,b) ((int)(&(((a*)(0))->b)))
```

What is it trying to do and what is the advantage of using it?

Comment: That `offsetof` macro is incorrect. They should cast to `size_t`, not `int`, and they should probably subtract `(char*)0` from the result before casting even though it's a null pointer constant.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It has no advantages and should not be used, since it invokes undefined behavior (and uses the wrong type - `int` instead of `size_t`).

The C standard defines an `offsetof` macro in `stddef.h` which actually works, for cases where you need the offset of an element in a structure, such as:

```
#include <stddef.h>

struct foo {
    int a;
    int b;
    char *c;
};

struct struct_desc {
    const char *name;
    int type;
    size_t off;
};

static const struct struct_desc foo_desc[] = {
    { "a", INT, offsetof(struct foo, a) },
    { "b", INT, offsetof(struct foo, b) },
    { "c", CHARPTR, offsetof(struct foo, c) },
};
```

which would let you programmatically fill the fields of a `struct foo` by name, e.g. when reading a JSON file.

Comment: I am sorry - how does the offsetof macro cause undefined behavior especially since its was defined in the C standard?

Comment: The standard `offsetof` macro from `stddef.h` does not invoke UB. Defining your own hack to compute offsets this way does invoke UB.

Comment: Please quote me the standard reference that says defining your own version of the macro causes undefined behaviour

Comment: @Adrian: He didn't say, "defining your own version of the macro causes undefined behaviour." He specifically said, "Defining your own hack to compute offsets **this way** does invoke UB." In the code, at this point: `((a*)(0))->` you've invoked undefined behavior by dereferencing null.

Comment: @GMan - where the hell have you referenced null its casting null as a a* pointer. And "Defining your own hack" is that a technical term for some code that I dont know after 20 years of C programming? let see how linux defines it #ifndef offsetof
# define offsetof(T,F) ((unsigned int)((char *)&((T *)0L)->F - (char *)0L))
#endif
Hmm look very similar to OP

Comment: @Adrian: `x->` is defined to be `(*x).`. In our case `x` is `(a*)0`, and `*x` dereferences null. And congrats: after twenty years of C you still don't know what implementation-defined behavior is. Quoting a specific definition on a specific implementation at a specific time has nothing to do with the language definition of the macro. The language states the *effects* of the macro and that's it, it doesn't define an implementation. I mean hell, you quoted the standard yourself; where in there does is state the definition of the macro?

Comment: @AdrianCornish: **The implementation** is allowed to define `offsetof` however it likes as long as it implements the correct behavior. **Your application** does not have this privilege because it can't define the behavior of anything; it can only use already-defined language constructs. That's how C works.

Comment: 6.5.2.3 does not use the word "dereference", but specifies it as "the named member of the object to which the first expression points". Since `(a*)(0)` does not point to an object of type `a`, the behavior is undefined (by virtue of not being defined).

Comment: [I love language standard debates] Which subclause (are you using c99) I cannot find one. I would argue: 6.3.2.3 Pointers
1 A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any incomplete or object type. A pointer to any incomplete or object type may be converted to a pointer to void and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

Comment: The text you cited is irrelevant. No pointer to incomplete or object type is converted to a pointer to void in the bogus macro.

Comment: @R.. what is the type of `foo_desc` here? Did you mean `food_desc[]` instead?

Comment: I added the `include` directive because it just felt *right* after [this edit suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14623034) got rejected.

Answer (score 47):

R.. is correct in his answer to the second part of your question: this code is not advised when using a modern C compiler.

But to answer the first part of your question, what this is actually doing is:

```
(
  (int)(         // 4.
    &( (         // 3.
      (a*)(0)    // 1.
     )->b )      // 2.
  )
)
```

Working from the inside out, this is ...

1. Casting the value zero to the struct pointer type `a*`
2. Getting the struct field b of this (illegally placed) struct object
3. Getting the address of this `b` field
4. Casting the address to an `int`

Conceptually this is placing a struct object at memory address zero and then finding out at what the address of a particular field is.  This could allow you to figure out the offsets in memory of each field in a struct so you could write your own serializers and deserializers to convert structs to and from byte arrays.

Of course if you would actually dereference a zero pointer your program would crash, but actually everything happens in the compiler and no actual zero pointer is dereferenced at runtime.

In most of the original systems that C ran on the size of an `int` was 32 bits and was the same as a pointer, so this actually worked.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. The key to me was `placing a struct object at memory address zero and then finding out at what the address of a particular field is`.

Answer (score 6):

It's finding the byte offset of a particular member of a `struct`.  For example, if you had the following structure:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    double d;
    int i;
    void *p;
};
```

Then you'd have `offsetOf(MyStruct, d) == 0`, `offsetOf(MyStruct, i) == 8`, and `offsetOf(MyStruct, p) == 12` (that is, the member named `d` is 0 bytes from the start of the structure, etc.).

The way that it works is it pretends that an instance of your structure exists at address 0 (the `((a*)(0))` part), and then it takes the address of the intended structure member and casts it to an integer.  Although dereferencing an object at address 0 would ordinarily be an error, it's ok to take the address because the address-of operator `&` and the member dereference `->` cancel each other out.

It's typically used for generalized serialization frameworks.  If you have code for converting between some kind of wire data (e.g. bytes in a file or from the network) and in-memory data structures, it's often convenient to create a mapping from member name to member offset, so that you can serialize or deserialize values in a generic manner.

Comment: The question is C, we still have to use `struct MyStruct`. ;)

Answer (score -3):

The implementation of the offsetof macro is really irrelevant.

The actual C standard defines it as in 7.17.3:

```
offsetof(type, member-designator)
```

which expands to an integer constant expression that has type size_t, the value of which is the offset in bytes, to the structure member (designated by member-designator), from the beginning of its structure (designated by type). The type and member designator shall be such that given `static type t;`.

Trust Adam Rosenfield's answer.

R is completely wrong, and it has many uses - especially being able to tell when code is non-portable among platforms.

(OK, it's C++, but we use it in static template compile time assertions to make sure our data structures do not change size between platforms/versions.)