# Variable being used after struct pointer declaration

Tags: c, linux

I'm from Brazil and I'm studying network socket programming in Linux. I'm very confused because I can't understand what this command does:

```c
char datagram[4096];
struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)datagram;
```

What is the `datagam` variable doing after `struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)` ? I can't understand the programming logic behind it.

I'm trying to decipher the programming logic behind it. Initially I thought that the `iph` pointer would be pointed to all members of the struct `iphdr` and at the same time it would also be pointed to the `datagram` variable. But I tried to access the `datagram` value via pointer and I couldn't.

Comment: `char datagram[4096];` allocates a 4096 bytes buffer on the stack and `struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)datagram;` casts that buffer to a `struct iphdr*`. Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57287466/type-casting-struct-pointer) helps.

Comment: `datagram` is an unintialized chunk of 4kb. `iph` points to the beginning of that same memory region. The `(struct iphdr*)` casts `datagram` to a pointer to `struct iphdr`. It basically tells the compiler "i know what I'm doing, so don't complain about a type mismatch". Unless you set the fields in `iph`, it's not going to be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first line allocates memory for a 4KB IP datagram. The datagram will have a header at the beginning, and the `iph` pointer can be used to access fields of that header by name using the members of the `iphdr` struct.

This will presumably be used with a raw socket, since that's the only way the IP header is normally made visible to socket code.

Comment: From what I understand, char datagrama will receive all the members of the struct iphdr and we can access these members (which are allocated in the datagram variable) using the pointer. Is correct?

Comment: @PedroHenrique you can access the bytes in the buffer using the pointer. But you may run into problems because a `char[]` doesn't require any special alignment while any non-char member within `struct iphdr` may require more restrictive alignment like even address, multiple of 4 bytes or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I have attached a sample code to understand better.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

/* Part of ipv4 header in TCP layer */
struct iphdr {
  unsigned char ver : 4; // 4 bits
  unsigned char ihl : 4; // 4 bits
  unsigned char tos;     // 8 bits = 1 byte
  int16_t total_length;  //  16 bits = 2 bytes
  /* others */
};
/*
  struct iphdr occupies 4 bytes in memory
  *---------------------------------------------------------------------*
  | total_length (2 bytes) | tos (1 byte) | ihl (4 bits) | ver (4 bits) |
  *---------------------------------------------------------------------*
 MSB                                                                  LSB
*/

int main(void) {
  char datagram[4096];
  struct iphdr* iph = (struct iphdr *)datagram;

  memset(datagram, 0, sizeof(datagram));

  // 61 = 0x3d = 0011 1101
  // 0011 = 3
  // 1101 = 13
  datagram[0] = 61;
  datagram[1] = 32;

  /*
    LSB                                            MSB
     +----------------------------------------------+
     | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 |     ...      |
     +----------------------------------------------+
     |            datagram[0]        | datagram[1]  |
     +----------------------------------------------+
     +-------------------------------+--------------+
     |    ihl        |      ver      |     tos      |
     +-------------------------------+--------------+
  */

  printf("%u\n", iph->ver);
  printf("%u\n", iph->ihl);
  printf("%u\n", iph->tos);

  return 0;
}
```

The result is

```
13
3
32
```

You have to search and understand of memory allocation in C structure and bit field of C structure also.

As you mentioned, the value can be, and should be accessed through the structure pointer and the char pointer. 
However, if you don't have access to datagram values, there will be other problems.
Please check the printf's format specifier or try to get data from datagram array by an index.

Comment: From what I understand, char datagrama will receive all the members of the struct iphdr and we can access these members (which are allocated in the datagram variable) using the pointer. Is correct?

Comment: @PedroHenrique Yes. I think so. all values to parse iphdr structure should be stored in datagram char array.