# How to find offset of a structure element in c when the structure does not have structure tag

Tags: c

I want to find offset of a structure element. I found some answers which suggested `offsetof(structure tag, element)` function. However, there are structures which do not have structure tag. For example:

```
struct {int a;} var;
```

How to handle these cases?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding offset of a structure element in c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749349/finding-offset-of-a-structure-element-in-c)

Comment: @TarekDakhran: I checked this question before asking this question. However, I did not think that I can use offsetof() function. But now I understand that I was wrong.

Comment: @ThuyNguyen - You also completely ignored the answers that don't use `offsetof` at all.

Comment: That's because you only read the first answer. Check @charlieBurns ' answer.

Comment: If you already have an instance of the structure, you don't need `offsetof`; `offsetof` works around the problem of being unable to compute offsets when you dont. You can simily do `((char *)&var.a - (char *)&var` to get the offset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your compiler supports it (i.e. gcc), you can combine it with the *typeof*  operator:

```
struct {int a, b; } var;
printf("%d\n", offsetof(typeof(var), b));
```

Comment: This isn't C but a GCC extension.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE Correct, I added this.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for not thinking deeply enough before asking. We can simply use `offsetof()` function as below:

```
offsetof(struct {int a;}, a)
```