# Copy part of struct using memcpy

Tags: c, struct, copy, member, memcpy

I am wondering if there is reliable and standard-compliant way to copy only memberes from certain position in struct. For example something like this

```
struct A {
  char* baz;
  int foo;
  int bar;
};

void copy(struct A* dst, const struct A* src) {
  dst->baz = malloc(1 + strlen(src->baz));
  strcpy(dst->baz, src->baz);
  memcpy(
    ((void*)dst) + sizeof(char*),
    ((void*)src) + sizeof(char*),
    sizeof(struct A) - sizeof(char*)
  );
}
```

Is this valid C and does not violate the standard? I know there may be some issues with memory alignment sometimes, I don't know if it applies to this scenario.

Second question is - how to do it when skipping more than one member because the padding issues start to rear their ugly heads then

Comment: There's a few ideas for the offset here: [Finding offset of a structure element in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18749349/243245). It might be simpler to just copy the whole lot and overwrite elements though rather than selectively copying the bits you're not setting.

Comment: There is no reliable way to do such a thing. You can `memcpy` each member individually, or the whole struct. Everything else will be UB, because of padding.

Comment: @flowit If I use `offsetof` for start and `sizeof-offsetof` for length, would that be UB?

Comment: Note that the result of `offsetof` is still compiler dependent, and does not work in all cases (for example not for bitfields). For your simple example it would actually work, but I recommend just copying the whole struct and replace the changed members.

Comment: @flowit The solution to that problem and many others, is to never use bit-fields.

Comment: @flowit assuming no bitfields it would be possible?

Answer (score 3):

- `void copy(A* dst, const A* src)` isn't valid C since you didn't typedef the struct. Change to `typedef struct {...} A;` if you wish to use this style.
- `strdup` is not valid C (but valid POSIX). I wouldn't recommend to use it for any purpose. Use `malloc` + `strcpy` instead (or `memcpy` if the size is known).
- `dst + sizeof(char*)` is nonsense since this does pointer arithmetic on whole structs. Same with `src + sizeof(char*)`.
- Fixing that bug, then there is still no guarantee that `(uint8_t*)dst + sizeof(char*)` gives the address of the member `foo`. The compiler is free to insert padding anywhere inside the struct (except before the very first member).

  You can reliably get the location of a specific member by `offsetof(struct A, foo)`, which gives you the number of bytes from the start of the struct to that specific member.

The sane way to copy a specific member of a struct is otherwise `dst->foo = src->foo;`. There is no apparent reason why your code shouldn't be doing this.

Similarly, you could copy specific members only and set the rest of them to zero/NULL, by using a compound literal:

```
*dst = (A){ .foo = src->foo };
```