# Moving pointer to desired location

Tags: c

I am offsetting my pointer as shown in the below code to copy to another structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct a
{
    int i;
};
struct test
{
    struct a *p;
    int x,y,z;
};

int main()
{
  struct test *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct test));
  struct test *q = malloc(sizeof(struct test));
  ptr->x = 10;
  ptr->y = 20;
  ptr->z = 30;
  memcpy(&(q->x),&(ptr->x),sizeof(struct test)-sizeof(struct a*));

  printf("%d %d %d\n",q->x,q->y,q->z);
  return 0;
}
```

Is there a better way to do my `memcpy()` ?
My question is what if I am in-cognizant of the members of the structure and want to just move my pointer by `sizeof(struct a*)` and copy rest of the structure?

Edits:

I want to copy some part of the structure but I don't know the members in it, but I know I want to skip some type of variable as shown in the example (struct a*) and copy rest of the structure.

Comment: The question is not very clear did you mean copying by traversing through the structure?

Comment: @GinuJacob Yeah.. I meant that I want to copy some part of the structure based on the type

Comment: Question unclear.   Do you mean that you want to copy all members of the struct, except `p`?

Comment: Use `offsetof(struct test, x)` (C99, gcc), not `sizeof(stuct a)`. They might not be guaranteed equal, because of padding/alignment.

Comment: I want to bring to your notice that `memcpy()` has no cognizance of the padding that structs may contain.

Comment: @Olaf Yeah that's what I was asking for..Can we move something like what you have shown ? Does that take care of padding and all?

Comment: I didn't really understand your question. Why doesn't `q->x = ptr->x;` suffice?

Comment: @ArjunSreedharan: Because "*... I don't know the members in it.*"

Comment: @alk Thanks for pitching in.. Can we do what I am trying to do? Just going by the pointer and the offset by size? I have 2 things 1. Pointer 2. type. I want to copy out the structure from `ptr + offset(type)`

Comment: Just see the two answers posted so far.

Answer (score 5):

Use `offsetof(struct test, x)` (C99, gcc), not `sizeof(stuct a *)`. They are not guaranteed equal, because of padding/alignment. **Caution:** As a result of padding, using `sizeof(..)` can result in *undefined behaviour*, as there are copied too many chars.

`offsetof(<type>, <member>)` returns the offset of  from the start of . So, `sizef(struct test) - offsetof(struct test, x)` yields the number of `char`s to copy all fields, starting with `x`.

[Just read here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180290/how-do-you-use-offsetof-on-a-struct)

Comment: @Gopi: I added another aspect, which renders your solution dangerous.

Answer (score 4):

I think the best way would be to use `offsetof`

```
memcpy(&(q->x),&(ptr->x),sizeof(struct test)-offsetof(struct test, x));
```

Because if first element was a little different, you could have alignment problems, whereas offsetof takes care of alignment for you.

Of course, alignement problems on a pointer should not occur on common architecture, but I think that `offsetof` is better practice anyway